# ggplot lengthen x scale for empty factor levels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a factor variable that has 0 observations in some factor levels.

I can successfully plot this using `geom_bar(drop=false)` but the x axis is too short:

[image]

I would like the x axis and its ticks to be same length/geometry as if I **did** have observations in levels 0,3 and 4:

[image]

As you can see in the above diagram there's enough space for levels 0 and 4 and the tick marks are in the right place. I'd like this behavior even if I have no observations in levels 0, 3 and 4.

---

Here's the code to generate the problematic plot:

```
# create the data frame
df = data.frame( species = c(1,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,1))

# set the species as factors
df$species = as.factor(df$species)

# we didn't see species 0, 3 or 4 but we still want to plot them
df$species = fct_expand(df$species,"0","3","4")

levels((df$species))

# re order the levels
df$species = factor(df$species,levels(df$species)[c(3,1,2,4,5)])

#check the levels look ok
table(df$species)

# plot
ggplot(data = df) + 
  scale_x_discrete(name = "species", expand = c(0, 0), drop = FALSE) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = species), stat = "Count", colour = "black", fill = "white", width = 1)
```

---

I've tried modifying `xlim` and `breaks` to no avail

Thanks

Comment: Remove `expand = c(0, 0)`.

Comment: thanks markus, that solves the problem at the species =4 end but not near the y axis

Comment: actually it does work, just not how I'd expected - Thank you